# why visual studio always try to look for dynamic boost library even I specified static lib

Tags: visual-c++, boost

In project properties->linker->input, I specify the static boost lib:

F:\boost_1_67_0\stage\lib\libboost_unit_test_framework-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_67.lib

But when link the project, it always try to find the dynamic library.

> Error LNK1104 cannot open file
>   'boost_unit_test_framework-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_67.lib'  test-suite  F:\proj\build64\LINK    1

boost_unit_test_framework-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_67.lib actually is the dynamic boost lib name

> > dir F:\boost_1_67_0\stage\lib\
>
> > > libboost_unit_test_framework-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_67.lib size:51M
>
> > dir F:\boost_1_67_0\stage\lib\dynamic\
>
> > > boost_unit_test_framework-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_67.lib  size:266k
> > >
> > > boost_unit_test_framework-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_67.dll  size:1.6M

I compiled boost according to  [this link](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/test/doc/html/boost_test/adv_scenarios/build_utf.html).

Comment: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#auto-linking

Comment: I rewrite the testcase with Catch. Catch is much better!!